# How to detect page has changed on Twitter with browser extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter, mutation-observers

I'm building a chrome extension to help automate pieces of the Twitter website.  As you navigate around, for example load the home page, then click a trends/search link, no jQuery "ready" or DOMContentLoaded event fires. Looking at the network trace, it indicates that the html for the next page is being loaded via ajax. I'd like to detect when this happens, short of monitoring the document.location with a setInterval or something similar.

I have looked at the DOMNodeRemoved event, but it fires for any node removed, and is a possible solution, but clumsy as it is frequently firing, not just for page changes and there is not a clear indicator that the page has changed.

```
$("body").on("DOMNodeRemoved", function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target, evt, this);
});
```

- I assume Twitter updates the location with pushState as the address bar does change. Is there an event when the location changes?  Or when it changes with pushState specifically?
- The ajax call is not mode with jQuery, so I can't hook that with jQuery global events. Is it possible to detect any XMLHttpRequest request?

What is a good way to capture the change of page?

Comment: there's  onpopstate. you can clobber window.XMLHttpRequest with a transparent proxy that also logs or invokes your other routines on each invocation.

Comment: Thanks, onpopstate does fire sometimes, when using the back and forward buttons, but not on the page change, bummer. Looking at proxy ideas now.

Comment: Having better luck with Mutation Observers and the Mutation Summary library. https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/